# Dynamically choosing template for django inclusion tag

Tags: django, django-templates

**Currently**

I have an inclusion tag that is coded something like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('forms/my_insert.html', takes_context=True)
def my_insert(context):
    # set up some other variables for the context
    return context
```

In my template, I include it by putting in `{% my_insert %}`

**New Feature Request**

We now want to test a new layout -- it's just a change to the template, no change to the context variables. I'm accomplishing this by calling the first

```
@register.inclusion_tag('forms/my_new_insert.html', takes_context=True)
def my_new_insert(context):
    return my_insert(context)
```

To use the new template, I have to use:

```
{% ifequal some_var 0 %}
    {% my_insert %}
{% endifequal %}
{% ifnotequal some_var 0 %}
    {% my_new_insert %}
{% endifnotequal %}
```

**The Question**

Is there a way to choose the template in the function which sets up the template tag context?

I *imagine* it might be something like:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('forms/my_insert.html', takes_context=True)
def my_insert(context):
    # set up some other variables for the context
    if context['some_var'] == 0:
        context['template'] = 'forms/my_insert.html'
    else:
        context['template'] = 'forms/my_new_insert.html'
    return context
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to manage same issue above and I resolved like this:

dummy.html

```
{% extends template %}
```

mytags.py

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('dummy.html')
def render_sample(template='default.html'):
    return {'template': template}
```

layout.html

```
{% load mytags %}

{% render_sample template="another_template.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own custom tag, with parameter which will be your template. Where is no way to use inclusion tag with several templates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@register.inclusion_tag('include/dummy.html')
def my_new_insert(template='forms/my_insert.html'):
    return {'template': template,
            'myvar': Myobject.objects.all()}
```

and take a look at [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: This didn't work when I tried it. I don't see any indication that it should in the documentation you linked to.